# loading parquet using petastorm to use it like tf.data.dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, petastorm

I've been trying to implement petastorm to load parquet straight into tensorflow. However I do not understand what is going on... After reading parquet file like:

```
with make_batch_reader(dataset_url_or_urls=filepath) as reader:
    dataset = make_petastorm_dataset(reader)
```

it returns `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1Adapter` then when I try to iterate over it I get following error

UnknownError: RuntimeError: Trying to read a sample after a reader created by make_reader/make_batch_reader has stopped. This may happen if the make_reader/make_batch_reader context manager has exited but you try to fetch a sample from it anyway
Traceback (most recent call last):

How do I fix this and also how to get tf.data.dataset instead of DatasetV1Adapter which I believe is old verson of tf.data.dataset